# Can I chain observables Like this.I implemented something but not sure it is the best way of doing this?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to transform data((meetingData$ | async)) using my custom pipe which is returning filtered arr as an observable.
Here is my code HTML:

```
<div class="meeting-dtls-sub-div" ***ngFor="let meeting of meetingData$ | async | hzCalendarFilter |async"**>
</div>
```

HzCalendarFilter.ts==

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'hzCalendarFilter',
})
export class HzCalendarFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  storedFilter$ = this.store$.pipe(select(getFilters));
  appliedFilterArr: string[] = [];
  constructor(private store$: Store<AppState>) {}
  transform(HzCaleDateArr: any = []) {
    return this.storedFilter$.pipe(
      map((filterArr: ICalendarFilter[]) => {
        this.appliedFilterArr = filterArr.filter((item) => item.isEnabled).map((data) => data.className);
        if (!!HzCaleDateArr) {
          return HzCaleDateArr.map((dateItem: any) => {
            return {
              ...dateItem,
              meetings: dateItem.meetings.filter((item: any) =>
                this.checkItemPresentOrNotAccordingToAppliedFilter(item.meetingType)
              ),
            };
          });
        }
      })
    );
  }
  checkItemPresentOrNotAccordingToAppliedFilter(meetingType: string) {
    const className = returnClassNameForMeeting(meetingType);
    if (!!className) {
      return this.appliedFilterArr.indexOf(className) > -1 ? true : false;
    }
  }
}
```

****Currently My code is working fine but I am not sure the way I am doing is ok or not?
Can someone plz let me know if using the async pipe chain like this (*ngFor="let meeting of meetingData$ | async | hzCalendarFilter |async") is ok or not??****

Comment: You are correct you can use multiple async pipe its not bad approach etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is fine if it works although I tought it might help.

if you are using ngrx you can use select with store itself like this

```
storedFilter$ = this.store$.pipe(select(getFilters));

to 

storedFilter$ = this.store$.select(getFilters)
```

you can use pipes for Observables also so you don't need to use async twice or more.

```
<div 
class="meeting-dtls-sub-div" 
*ngFor="let meeting of meetingData$ | hzCalendarFilter | async">

  ...

</div>
```

We can write filters inside your store pipe to filter out disabled ones:

```
storedFilter$ = this.store$.pipe(select(getFilters));
this.appliedFilterArr = filterArr.filter((item) => item.isEnabled).map((data) => data.className)

to

enabledStoredFilter$: Observable<string[]> = this.store$.select(getFilters).pipe(
    map((arr: ICalendarFilter[]) => {
      return arr.filter((x) => x.isEnabled);
    }),
    map((arr: ICalendarFilter[]) => arr.map((x) => x.className))
  );
```

And complete code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
interface ICalendarFilter {
  isEnabled: boolean;
  className: string;
}
interface AppState {}
interface DateItem {
  meetings: string[];
}

function returnClassNameForMeeting(name: any): any {}
@Pipe({
  name: 'hzCalendarFilter'
})
export class HzCalendarFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  enabledStoredFilter$: Observable<string[]> = this.store$.select(getFilters).pipe(
    map((arr: ICalendarFilter[]) => {
      return arr.filter((x) => x.isEnabled);
    }),
    map((arr: ICalendarFilter[]) => arr.map((x) => x.className))
  );

  constructor(private store$: Store<AppState>) {}

  transform(hzCaleDateArr$: Observable<DateItem[]>) {
    return hzCaleDateArr$.pipe(this.applyStoreFilters);
  }

  get applyStoreFilters() {
    return switchMap((arrayOfDateItems: DateItem[]) => {
      return this.enabledStoredFilter$.pipe(
        map((filters) => {
          return this.addMeetingsToDateItemArray(arrayOfDateItems, filters);
        })
      );
    });
  }

  addMeetingsToDateItemArray(arrayOfDateItems: DateItem[], appliedFilterArr: string[]) {
    return arrayOfDateItems.map((dateItem: DateItem) => this.filterMeetingOfDateItem(dateItem, appliedFilterArr));
  }

  filterMeetingOfDateItem(dateItem: DateItem, filtersToApply) {
    const meetings = dateItem.meetings.filter((item: any) => {
      const className = returnClassNameForMeeting(item.meetingType);
      if (!!className) {
        return filtersToApply.indexOf(className) > -1;
      }
    });

    return {
      ...dateItem,
      meetings
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Need one small clarification like why you have used switchMap in  applyStoreFilters()?

Comment: It changes the stream to another observable. every time you get a data from pipe it will change the stream to store filter observable.